# TSQL Subquery related

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

```
SELECT DT.TenantDescription
    ,DT.PropertyNumber
    ,DT.UnitNo
    ,DT.AdressLn1
    ,DT.AddressLn2
    ,DT.AddressSituation
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN DT.TransactionCode = 1
                THEN DT.New_TransactionValue
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS RentDue
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN DT.TransactionCode = 2
                THEN DT.New_TransactionValue
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS OTHERSUMSDUE
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN DT.TransactionCode = 3
                THEN DT.New_TransactionValue
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS ARREARSBFWD
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN DT.TransactionCode = 4
                THEN DT.New_TransactionValue
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS ARREARSCFWD
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN DT.TransactionCode = 5
                THEN DT.New_TransactionValue
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS IRRECOVERABLERENT
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN DT.TransactionCode > 5
                THEN DT.New_TransactionValue
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) AS Expenditure
FROM (
    SELECT * * (
            SELECT New_TenantNameOnly
            FROM New_Rentmaster Rm
            WHERE Rm.New_rentmasterId = PD.new_rentmasterid
            ) AS TenantDescription
        ,* * (
            SELECT [New_UnitNumber]
            FROM new_propertyunits NPU
            WHERE NPU.[New_propertyunitsId] = PD.[new_unitnumberid]
            ) AS UnitNo
        ,(
            SELECT New_AddressLine1
            FROM New_address
            WHERE New_addressId = (
                    SELECT New_addressid
                    FROM New_PropertyMaster PM
                    WHERE PM.new_propertymasterid = PD.[new_propertynumbernameid]
                    )
            ) AS AdressLn1
        ,(
            SELECT New_AddressLine2
            FROM New_address
            WHERE New_addressId = (
                    SELECT New_addressid
                    FROM New_PropertyMaster PM
                    WHERE PM.new_propertymasterid = PD.[new_propertynumbernameid]
                    )
            ) AS AddressLn2
        ,(
            SELECT TT.[New_TransactionTypeCode] AS TransactionCode
            FROM New_transactiontype TT
            WHERE [New_transactiontypeId] = PD.[new_transactioncodenameid]
            ) AS TransactionCode
        ,(
            SELECT New_PropertyNumber
            FROM New_PropertyMaster PM
            WHERE PM.new_propertymasterid = PD.[new_propertynumbernameid]
            ) AS PropertyNumber
        ,(
            SELECT New_UnitAddressIdName
            FROM New_propertyunits NPU
            WHERE NPU.[New_propertyunitsId] = PD.[new_unitnumberid]
            ) AS AddressSituation
        ,PD.New_TransactionValue
    FROM New_PropertyDetails PD
    ) AS DT
```

The above piece of code works fine

Now I want to make changes to the above column (the name is aliased to `TenantDescription`)
where I want to replace the above column with the following code

```
Select New_TenantNameOnly from New_Rentmaster Rm    
  New_TenantNumber IN 
     (Select MAX(New_TenantNumber) from new_rentmaster GROUP BY [New_Unit_No],[New_Propety_Number])
```

then it gives me an error

> Subquery returns more than one value

This code is supposed to return more than one value

So what should I do about it >??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Format your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to bring back multiple results, you ought to be thinking about using *joins* rather than subqueries. An [Inner Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS p
ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
```

this will produce as many rows as can be produced by matching rows from each table based on the `ON` condition (e.g. if there are two rows in `Employee` with `BusinessEntityID` of 1, and three rows in `Person` with `BusinessEntityID` of 1, the above will produce six rows in the result set where `BusinessEntityID` is 1)

Comment: At the same time i am looking for an answer that makes use of SubQueries instead of Joins as per the business requirement

Comment: @OneThinker - since a subquery in a select clause *cannot* return more than one value, you have to decide between "produces the results I want" and "there's a **business** requirement that I use subqueries" - since I can't fathom how the second of these makes sense, I would go with the first.